# Round Robin Memory Scheduling with CPU & Memory Visualisations

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, scheduled-tasks, gantt-chart, round-robin

For a Round Robin implementation, I have 5 processes with their arrival & duration times and the memory needed to be processed, as shown below.

[5 Processes accessing the CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9p1s.png)

The total memory of the system is 512K and the time quantum used is 3. Based on the Round Robin theory I created the following Gantt graph.

[Gantt Graph creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpAYl.jpg)

I have to represent on the following table, the visualisation of the memory and the CPU until time interval t=10 by showcasing the processes that are on CPU queue (which I did on the graph), which parts of the memory have been occupied by the processes and which are free, by using i) a system with variable diviations without compaction and ii) with compaction.

[Table of Results to be created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNout.png)

I suppose that I have to adjust the memory usage of each process accordingly with the quantum time given at 3. For example, for process P1 the duration is equal to the quantum time and thus, the whole 85K of it will be used. If I that assumption is correct, the system I am using runs without compaction? How can I proceed the next steps with compaction?

Thank you in advance